# Scroll an NSScrollView to Top-Left corner, programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Well, that's what I'm trying to do but without success so far.

**That's what I tried :**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[_myScrollView contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0,[[_myScrollView contentView] bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing your current code will scroll to the bottom left of the scroll view (because of `[[_myScrollView contentView] bounds].size.height` as the y coordinate of the point). Have you tried using: `NSMakePoint(0, 0)` as the argument to `scrollToPoint:`?

Comment: Log the value `[[_myScrollView contentView] bounds].size.height`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[[_myScrollView contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0,0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSPoint newScrollOrigin = NSMakePoint(0.0,NSMaxY([[_myScrollView documentView] frame])
                          -NSHeight([[_myScrollView contentView] bounds]));

[[_myScrollView documentView] scrollPoint:newScrollOrigin];
```

To know more see this link -

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html